# ANTLR Language Support for VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, antlr4

Will the language support eventually support VS 2017? Just tried to install it and it fails since the VSIX doesn't specify support for 2017.

Would be awesome to have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about the state of development of a third-party plugin to Microsoft Visual Studio.

Comment: To be honest, I'd love to have VS 2017 support, too, despite the question being off-topic for the SO site. It should be directed to antlr people who maintain the plug-in.

Comment: IIRC the ANTLR team are asking people to post questions here, so I don't believe it to be off-topic.

Comment: Although I just now saw that they are also using a Google forum. Didn't last time I checked which, admittedly, has been a while.

Comment: Try [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) (and the [ANTLR4 extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4) for it) instead.

Comment: I did see a reference to that. Our project is a TFS solution and we use VS quite heavily so the integration into VS would be preferable.